# Does downloading torrents to an AirDisk affect my internal SSD?

Tags: mac, ssd, bittorrent, airport-extreme

I gather that it's not recommended to download torrents using an SSD (due to the high number of write operations, the SSD will be worn out pretty fast).

I've changed to an AirDisk connected through my Airport Extreme for downloading torrents (uTorrent for Mac). Will this wear out the SSD on my MacBook Pro?

Comment: I wish this limited write operation myth about SSDs would die. Newer SLC drive aren't at any more disadvantage than a mechanical drive. . .

Answer (score 1):

No. At least it won't wear it out more than any other program does. The high number of write operations occur in the Air Disk, where the files are being stored.

The data is received in your computer's memory (as long as you have enough RAM available) and then sent directly to the Air Disk without going through the SSD. The only thing that will increase is the traffic inside your local network.

If you are still unsure, open Activity Monitor and check the Disk Activity.